Implementing a Stack in Python: Problem with the POP function
I'm trying to implement the Stack Data Structure in Python from scratch. Unfortunately, I have a problem with the pop functionality.
The pop function should delete the top element of the stack. Unfortunately, in my implementation, running pop and then printing the array returns the same array as before the pop function.
How to better implement the pop function? I could do self.top = self.top.prev, but I am not sure if in the Stack Data Structure we have access to previous elements.
# FOLLOWS LIFO


class StackElement:
    def __init__(self, value, prev=None, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.prev = prev # Not sure if this is available in the Stack DS...
        self.next = next


class Stack:
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.bottom = None
        self.top = None

        for v in values:
            self.push(v)

    def __str__(self):
        res = [str(x.value) for x in self]
        return " -> ".join(res)

    def __iter__(self):
        current = self.bottom
        while current:
            yield current
            current = current.next

    def __len__(self):
        res = 0
        current = self.bottom
        while current:
            res += 1
            current = current.next
        return res

    def push(self, value):
        if self.bottom is None:
            self.bottom = self.top = StackElement(value)
        else:
            self.top.next = StackElement(value)
            self.top = self.top.next
        return self.top

    def pop(self):
        if not self.is_empty():
            self.top = None
        return self.top

    def peek(self):
        if not self.is_empty():
            return self.top

    def is_empty(self):
        if len(self) != 0:
            return False
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Stack(["2", "3", "4"])
    print(s)
    s.push("5")
    print(s, s.top.value, s.bottom.value)
    s.pop()
    print(s, s.top, s.bottom.value)
    res = [str(x.value) for x in s]
    print(res)
    print(s)


Console Output:
2 -> 3 -> 4
2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 5 2
2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 None 2
['2', '3', '4', '5']
2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5


Picture a stack of two elements. Now run your pop(): the top element is still at bottom.next, you just removed the information that it is top from top.

Unrelated, but your stack peek (and top) should not return StackElement objects, but their value attribute. And push should not return anything.

The assignment self.top = None in your pop method will not achieve what you want. It will just update that top attribute, but the node that precedes it will still link to that element via its next attribute. You really need to break that link by setting the appropriate next attribute to None. Also, you don't want to set top to None just like that. After the pop action there might still be more elements below that top, and the top attribute should be updated to reference that element that now has become the top of the stack.
Besides this issue there are some other remarks to make:

In StackElement, don't name that parameter next, as that is the name of a native Python function. Use some other name, like nxt. For naming an attribute there is no such confusion possible, so that self.next can stay.

You have implemented a doubly linked list, but actually you only need a singly linked list. As you only pop from the "top" side, you only need prev, not next.

We could also omit bottom for a pure stack, but then we need to reconsider your iteration direction. Iterating over a stack is not really a plain stack feature, but if you do want to have it, it makes sense to iterate from top to bottom, and not from bottom to top. Then you can leave out bottom as well.

In __len__ you iterate the whole stack, which will work, but if you add an attribute to your stack that keeps track of the current length, then you can avoid this loop.

Your methods should not return StackElement instances. This should be considered private information. Only provide an interface with values that are stored in the stack, never the nodes. This also applies to __iter__. To indicate that the top attribute is private, prefix it with underscore.

The push method should not have to return anything (just None).

The StackElement has prev as optional argument. Using this argument in your push method can greatly reduce code.

is_empty can simply verify the length or the value of the top attribute and turn that into a boolean. No need for an if statement here.


Here is your code with the above remarks taken into account:
class StackElement:
    # Don't name argument "next", but you actually don't need it
    def __init__(self, value, prev=None):
        self.value = value
        self.prev = prev # No need for next

class Stack:
    def __init__(self, values):
        # Use underscore to indicate these are considered private
        self._top = None  # No need for bottom
        self._len = 0  # Maintain length to avoid counting in __len__

        for v in values:
            self.push(v)

    def __str__(self):
        # Don't create a list. The iterator is enough for join
        # We reverse the arrow, because the iteration starts at the top
        return " <- ".join(map(str, self))

    def __iter__(self):
        current = self._top  # Start at top to avoid the bottom ref.
        while current:
            yield current.value  # Don't expose nodes, only values
            current = current.prev

    def __len__(self):
        return self._len

    def push(self, value):
        # Provide the prev argument to simplify code:
        self._top = StackElement(value, self._top)
        self._len += 1 # Keep length updated
        # Push should not return anything

    def pop(self):
        if not self.is_empty():
            value = self._top.value
            self._top = self._top.prev
            self._len -= 1  # Keep length updated
            return value  # Return value, not a node

    def peek(self):
        if not self.is_empty():
            return self._top.value # Return value, not a node

    def is_empty(self):
        return not self._top # no if statement needed 


Thank you for SUCH a detailed answer!!! I have a few questions: why do I need to return the value in pop? Cant i just self the new self top value, and minimize the length? Is its faster to store length like this? I believe that calling len now (after your changes) would be O(1) and before it was O(n) - but I am not sure - that's why I'm asking :) Also in the is_empty - why is it a mistake to use the if loop? Thanks so much once again for taking your time!

(1) There is no must to have pop return the value, but Python native pop methods (for list, deque, dict,...) all return the value that is popped, so it would be natural to do it here like that too. Note that if you don't return it, then the caller must first look at the top value (maybe with a peek method), and only then call pop. Although it is done like that in some other programming languages, it is not the habit in Python.

(2) Managing the length with an extra attribute, only adds O(1) work to the push and pop methods, so that is worth the effort, as indeed you save O(n) work for the loop. If the caller makes lots of use of the len function, then this matters.

(3) is_empty was not in a loop ;-) Using an if is not wrong in the sense that it would malfunction, but it is just better coding practice to return a boolean expression instead of testing that boolean expression and return False or True depending on it.

(1) Great :) I remembered pop works similarly, although I never understood why. The len() function tip was great, helps definitely to reduce the complexity. Thank you :))

I tried to simplify logic for you. Read added comments to understand. In my opinion, using .next or .previous suits to linked lists.
Code:
# FOLLOWS LIFO

class StackElement:
    def __init__(self, value): 
        self.value = value


class Stack:
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = [] #all values in stack
        self.top = -1 #current element index

        for v in values: 
            self.push(v) 

    def __str__(self):
        res = [str(x) for x in self.values]
        return " -> ".join(res)

    def __iter__(self):
        end = 0
        while end:
            yield self.values[end]
            end += 1

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.values) #return list size simply

    def push(self, value):
        self.values.append(value) #assuming if there is no max size of stack, then push at the end of list
        self.top += 1 #current index + 1 as one element is added

    def pop(self):
        if not self.is_empty(): #atleast one element in stack
            self.values = self.values[:self.top] #overwrite list without the last element to follow lifo
            self.top -= 1 #current index - 1 as one element is removed

    def peek(self):
        if not self.is_empty():
            return self.values[self.top] #return last element in list

    def is_empty(self):
        if len(self.values) != 0:
            return False
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Stack(["2", "3", "4"])
    print(s)
    s.push("5")
    print(s, s.top)
    s.pop()
    print(s, s.top)
    res = [str(x) for x in s.values]
    print(res)
    print(s)

Output:
2 -> 3 -> 4
2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 3
2 -> 3 -> 4 2
['2', '3', '4']
2 -> 3 -> 4

As programmers, it is better not to overcomplicate code as it saves time and memory. Have a great day!

Maintaining the values in a list seems contrary to the purpose of the asker to build the stack "from scratch".

Unfortnately, like the commenter above said, using a list here is unideal, the whole point of creating a Stack class was NOT to use a list. Using a list would require no class creation and could be used as is.

Correct, I should have paid attention to from scratch.
